# Chromedriver is suddenly displaying a strange warning about blocking third party cookies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here's my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from flask import Flask, render_template
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

APP = Flask(__name__)

@APP.route('/ohc_search_link')
def ohc_search_link():
    ohc_search()
    return render_template("finished.html")    

def ohc_search():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://docs.oracle.com/')
    
    # More scraping code here ...
    
    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #start OHC search
    APP.run()
```

When I run this, I see this warning on the console:

`[0203/171925.768:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.", source: https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=recruiting&pg=1&size=10&showfirstpage=true&lang=en`

My script runs fine though and I'm seeing the results I expect. But can I ignore this warning? If yes, is there a way to suppress it?

I wasn't seeing any warnings a few days earlier. I remember that my chrome browser updated around that time. I'm seeing this warning after that update.

Do you think this is related to this news about [restricting third party cookies](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/blog/cookie-countdown-2024jan)? But strangely I don't see the Eye icon on the website I'm scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this error too. Try adding the following:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
```